# Private key encryption over TCP java (Android) /C#

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption, tcp

I’m new on encryption.

I'm programming 2 app one for Android (JAVA) and other for Windows (C#), so I need to encrypted messages between them over TCP.

**I wonder if someone could tell if what I thought is OK or there is a better and easy way.**

So I thought on a symmetric encryption where I **don't have to worry about certificates installations on Android devices**. As consequence I thought this protocol of messages between apps.

[image]
which I want to know is OK or not.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the point of the salt and the 1 shot private keys? Seems unnecessary and could be a potential vulnerability. And how does Android and the server establish the same privatekey1?

Comment: First thanks for your comment! My idea was to use the salt and iv to randomize the encrypted message. Maybe I misunderstood but I thought the iv and salt doesn't need to keep secret, so every time I use both apps I don't need to put a new privatekey1 (initial). Answering your last question as it is a private key I can enter the privatekey1 manually on both devices.

Comment: If you have existing manually entered keys, use a key derivation protocol like ECDHE to generate another set of session keys (and use these for the rest of the session). You don't need to create so many keys, it doesn't add anything to your security and creates a small vulnerability. Using an IV alone is sufficient to create "randomness" in a good chaining scheme (for block ciphers). And don't include your IV in your message if you're already using a salt. Like SteffenUllrich said though, if you're not experienced, don't roll your own, copy one first or read about crypto until you are good.

Answer (score 2):

> I’m new on encryption.
>
> ... I thought this protocol of messages ...I don't have to worry about certificates installations on Android devices

Please don't roll your own crypto, especially if you know that you are new to it. There are enough broken crypto protocols already out there so you can safely assume that you will not succeed in making a safe protocol with your current knowledge.

And there is a reason certificates are usually used with TLS. They are used to securely identify the peer of the communication and if you don't have this kind of identification you are open to man-in-the-middle attacks. If you have different methods you can use them, because TLS does not require the use of certificates, but certificates is the most common way for identification. So no need to roll your own crypto, even if you use other ways of identifying the peer outside of certificates.

Apart from that, a much better place to ask this kind of questions is security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks Steffen! Could you please tell me about some site where I can learn how to use TLS without certificates on Java and C#, because I found ones that advise the use of self-signed certificates. But I don’t want to use any kind of certificate, because I don’t want to install certificates on Android devices.

Comment: I don't think you really understand the issue about the necessary identification of the peer. And you don't need to install certificates on the system if your application expects only specific certificates and checks only their fingerprint. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning might be a good start to read about it.